# Angular custom filtering by condition in HTML doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I'm pretty new in angular, so my question may looks simple or stupid, but I didn't found any solution.
I have a collection in my controller (for example, a collection of integers) and I want to filter it and take items for which condition is true.

At first I tried this:

```
<div>{{myCollection.find(item => item === 2)}}</div>
```

and it didn't work.
Then I found another approach (which one I don't like because I will always have only single element to show and there is no need in peretition):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list | filter:{item === 2}">
    <div>{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

And it also doesn't work.
Here is JSBin with my efforts: http://jsbin.com/govovocace/1/edit?html,js,output

Is there any possible solution of my problem? Calculating the required field in controller and passing it to the view doesn't suit me (unfortunately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had syntactical mistake. You should not be mentioning any `object` inside filter as you're directly filtering actual object which you are looping on. The last option `true` is because we are going to perform exact check.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list | filter: 2: true">
    <div>{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/c4r9HKJWXVx62G5Ug4BO?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is exactly what I was looking for! I wish I had enough reputation to upvote your answer and mark it as accepted :)

Comment: I think you have it enough, Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a filter function in your controller like so:

```
$scope.filterFn = function(val){
    return val === 2;
};
```

And then use it in your template like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list | filter:filterFn">
    <div>{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

Tha said, this is equivalent to just filtering the array to begin with, so i'm not sure if this meets your needs or not. If you have a particular use case this doesn't suit let me know in the comments.

Comment: Thanks! It also works, but Pankaj's answer suits me more because I don't change controller. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

i would have done something like this

```
.controller('SomeController',function($scope){

 // get the list from somewhere
  $scope.list  = [] // some array for instance

  $scope.dataList = list.filter(function(i){
     return i.someVal==list.someVal; // condition that satisfy your req
  });

});
```

and now use it in view as

```
<div ng-repeat=" item in dataList"> 
   {{item}}
</div>
```

if your condition will return only one result then you can do

```
$scope.dataList = list.filter(function(i){
         return i.someVal==list.someVal; // condition that satisfy your req
      })[0];
```

Comment: Sorry, this solution doesn't suit my case. I don't have data in $scope in controller - it adds there somewhere later, so I can't filter it inside. I know it sounds strange, but that is true.